# Read data from closed XLSX book without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using MS Excel 2017. I have few workbook named in certain format. XLSX file names are same as the ticker name.

```
D:\Working Base\Base.xlsx
D:\Working Base\Data\1INCH.xlsx 
D:\Working Base\Data\AAVE.xlsx
D:\Working Base\Data\ADA.xlsx
D:\Working Base\Data\ALGO.xlsx
D:\Working Base\Data\AMP.xlsx
```

In the Base.xlsx file I'm trying to read file contents under "Data" folder matching the ticker name. So, if the ticker name is 1INCH then data XLSX file name will be 1INCH.xlsx. If I try to read data from a closed xlsx file manually by writing each line that works fine but I can't drag the first line and do the same for other lines.

[image]

```
=IFERROR('D:\Working Base\Data\[1INCH.xlsx]Dashboard'!$R$8, "")
```

I tried to make the file path but its not working.

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT("'D:\Working Base\[", A3, ".xlsx]Dashboard'!$R$8"),"")
```

I've searched different contents from internet. Nothing seems working. Is it at all possible or I'm doing something wrong. Appreciate any kind help.

Comment: Have you tried writing the formula and when referencing the file/range, actual clicking the range in the opened workbook? Excel then uses reference to that file. After closing that file Excel dynamically changes the reference.

Comment: It cannot be done without VBA. Let us know if that's an option. You can try e.g. `=INDIRECT("'D:\Working Base\Data\["&A3&".xlsx]Dashboard'!$R$8")` but the problem is *"If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value."* quoted from Microsoft Docs' [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

Comment: @P.b : I've tried that. Only problem is I've over 100 data files. Its difficult keep them all open.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Yes, I've tried with Indirect and it works as long as the data files are open as you've mentioned. As mentioned to P.b I've over 100 data files. So, its not an option. I will check the VB codes in other tickets. You can also submit an answer here, I will accept those as long as I can make it work. Thank you guys!

Comment: If you try it with one file you see how Excel changes the Network notification. Following that logic you can link to the others. It requires opening and closing only 1 file.

Answer (score 1):

### Reference Cells in Closed Workbooks (VBA)

- If you don't have the developer tab, go to `Excel>Options>Customize Ribbon` and tick `Developer` in the right list box, and press `OK`.
- Go to the `Ribbon` and select `Developer` and click on `Visual Basic` which will open the `Visual Basic Editor` (`VBE`) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).
- Select `VBE>View>Project Explorer` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). In the `Project Explorer` window double click the appropriate project (`VBAProject(your file...)`).
- Double-click the appropriate worksheet (it's tab name is the name in parentheses).
- Copy the code into the newly opened sheet code window (its title may be different because it uses the code name (the name not in parentheses)).
- Adjust the six values in the constants section.
- Exit the VBE (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and you're good to go.
- Although the code will work already, you need to save the workbook with a `.xlsm` extension.
- As you manually (not by formula) change a value in column `A`, triggering the `Worksheet Change event`, the appropriate result (a reference or an empty string) will be written to the same row in column `B`.
- Keep in mind that it will fail if you save the source workbooks in another destination (it will not update).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const sfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const dCol As String = "B"
    Const dWorksheetName As String = "Dashboard"
    Const dFolderPath As String = "D:\Working Base\Data\"
    Const dFileExtension As String = ".xlsx"
    Const drCellAddress As String = "$R$8"
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = Me.Range(sfCellAddress)
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sfCell.Resize(Me.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(scrg, Target)
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' before writing to the same worksheet
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim dBaseName As String
    Dim dFormula As String
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        dBaseName = CStr(sCell.Value)
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & dBaseName & dFileExtension
        If Len(Dir(dFilePath)) > 0 Then
            dFormula = "=IFERROR('" & dFolderPath & "[" & dBaseName _
                & dFileExtension & "]" & dWorksheetName & "'!" _
                & drCellAddress & ","""")"
        Else
            dFormula = ""
        End If
        'Debug.Print dFormula
        sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Formula = dFormula
    Next sCell

SafeExit:
    If Application.EnableEvents = False Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' after writing
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```